# Расшифровка cookies google-chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome, password

Не получается расшифровать encrypted_value, выводится такая строка:

```
b'v10\x18\x06E\x04j\xc5\x98\x86\x13[\xaf\xd3j\xbf!\xd8P\xc3\x8f\x92\xecV\xcc\xbb\x03Hd\xba\xd9\x91\tb<\xcb\xc7>\xc7\xf6#f^.\xbd\x87\xca!\xb2\x96u0\xd3\x82>5\xe09\n\x9b\xbe\xbd\xad\xf4Ta\xf5o\xf3\xc5\x9a\xe9\x95^5_0:\xbf\xc58\x0fDD\xe19\xa0\xe5&q\x12f\xd8\xf8\xb4\xce\x0
```

Так понимаю это двоичное значение, а как его расшифровать не очень догоняю

```
import os 
import shutil
import base64 
import sqlite3
import win32crypt
import re
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES

Chrome_cookies = os.getenv('LOCALAPPDATA') + r"\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Login Data"
Key = os.getenv('LOCALAPPDATA') + r"\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State"

def chrome_cookies():
    if os.path.exists(Chrome_cookies) == True:
        with open (Key, 'r') as f:
            matches = re.findall(r'"encrypted_key":"(.+?)"', f.read())
            key = base64.b64decode(matches[0])[5:]
            decryption_key2 = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(key, None, None, None, 0)[1]
            shutil.copy2(Chrome_cookies, 'databasepasss.db')
            conn = sqlite3.connect('databasepasss.db')
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute('SELECT host_key, name, encrypted_value FROM cookies')
            show = cursor.fetchall()
         with open ('D:\\cookies.txt', 'w+') as f:
            for host_key, name, encrypted_value in show:
                initialization_vector = encrypted_value[3:15]
                password = encrypted_value[15:-16]
                gsm = AES.new(decryption_key2, AES.MODE_GCM,initialization_vector)
                decrypted_cookies = gsm.decrypt(password)
                paass = decrypted_cookies.decode()
                text = 'Host key: ' + host_key + '\n' +'\n' + 'Name: ' + name + '\n' + '\n' + 'encrypted_value: ' + str(encrypted_value)  + '\n' + '\n' + '============' + '\n' + '\n'
                print(text)
                    f.write(text)
              
chrome_cookies()
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему возникает ошибка "path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer" при дешифровке cookies?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1520423/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-path-should-be-string-bytes-os-pathlike-or-integer-%d0%bf)